# How should a small robotics startup go about building a data platform?

Tags: slam, data, machine-learning, unit-testing

We're a small company making ROS based robots that rely heavily on SLAM and perception. We're looking for a data platform solution, something like Foxglove or formant.io as a base data management tool, and then capabilities of EMR on top to run batch jobs (simulations, inference tests, etc) on the accumulated data. My questions are:

- Has anyone had experience with either for this type of application? What are your experiences?
- If we decide to bolt a data processing pipeline on top of either (or we build our own storage), what are some best practices? Would appreciate to be pointed to blogs or books, I can find surprisingly little on Google on this subject.

Of course, if there's an all-in-one product that does all of the above, would love to learn about it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Being transparent: I work at Foxglove. We have quite a few customers that use the data platform for exactly what you're describing. You can use the [stream APIs](https://docs.foxglove.dev/api#tag/Stream-data) to stream data into your post processing tools. As a place to get started, you can [try doing this into a Jupyter notebook](https://foxglove.dev/blog/analyze-your-robotics-data-with-jupyter-notebooks).